# How to turn an electromagnet on and off?

Tags: switches, electromagnetism

I need to control an electromagnet as follows:

I need to switch it on/off every T seconds, where T is around 1 second.
I need to be able to change that time, using something like a potentiometer.

Which components do I need?

*Please take into mind that I don't have much electronic knowledge (learning physics in school, including electromagnetism).*

Answer (score 5):

You really have two problems: generating a time interval, and driving an inductive load.

For the timing you could use an analog circuit such as a 555 timer, or you could use a micro-controller running a simple program.  Either can use a variable resistor to set the value - the 555 uses it to control the time constant of charging a capacitor, the micro-controller can read it via an ADC or similarly in a capacitor time constant measurement if the micro doesn't have an ADC.  The analog circuit will be simpler to document and understand, and can be developed with fewer tools, while the micro-controller will be more versatile for variations on the task and potentially more accurate if a crystal or resonator is used as the clock reference.

The common way to drive the coil is likely with a general purpose NPN transistor on the ground side of the supply circuit - emitter to ground, collector to the coil, and a resistor feeding the base from the timing circuit.  It would be a good idea to place a fast switching diode "backwards" across the coil to handle the inductive kick which occurs when it is switched off.  You don't mention the specs of the electromagnet, so it's hard to recommend a specific transistor.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will read about everything you mentioned. The electromagnet is probably this one or similar: http://www.ebay.com/itm/25mm-OD-24V-Holding-Electromagnet-Lift-5kg-Solenoid-/290642055555?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43ab9dd183#ht_2667wt_1396

Comment: Probably your first task will be to determine the current - you can calculate it from the wattage and voltage, or measure the resistance and calculate it that way, or measure it directly while powering the coil with a suitably rated ammeter inline (start on a higher current scale, then work down)

Comment: According to the seller it is 24V and 4W, therefore 1/6A.
I can't be sure that we will be using it on it's maximal voltage, but I guess the current will be around that.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the timing, Chris has given you a good answer. A 555 is probably appropriate (choose a CMOS variety like the TLC555); the only reasons I'd use a microcontroller over a 555 are:

- to work with a more complicated switching pattern, or one that depends on some other input
- if you needed extremely low power operation (e.g. electromagnet comes on for 1 second out of each day) -- there aren't any 555 variants, to my knowledge, that are truly micropower, and they draw too much current to use on battery power for long periods of time.

As far as the switching goes, for low voltages I would almost surely use a MOSFET as it is easier to design without having to worry about power dissipation -- NPN transistors typically have between 0.1V - 0.4Vce drop when fully turned on, so multiply that by the electromagnet current and there's heat you have to dissipate. MOSFETs have an on-resistance, and unless you are switching high-power loads thousands of times per second, you just have to handle I2R losses.

I wrote [a blog entry](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/77.php) a while back that might help you understand how to interface an electromagnet with digital logic.